# Chess Board Exercise

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon.

I started a Javascript course 2 weeks ago. Been studying the basics and doing some simple exercise. Now i'm stuck. I have to make a chess board using HTML and Javascript, and i should ask the user the number of squares he wants and the width of those squares. The exercise says i must resolve it using functions, and i tried for a while but have no idea how to even start. I did this code but i think it's all wrong so can anyone give me a hand?

```
        function chess(pBoardNumber, pBoardWidth) {
           document.write('<div "width: ' + pBoardNumber + ' px; height: ' + pBoardWidth + 'px; style= background-color: black"></div>');     
        }

        function chess(pBoardNumber, pBoardWidth) {
           document.write('<div "width: ' + pBoardNumber + ' px; height: ' + pBoardWidth + 'px; style= background-color: white"></div>');    
        }


        function chess(pBoardNumber, pBoardWidth) {
           document.write('<div "width: ' + pBoardNumber + ' px; height: ' + pBoardWidth + 'px; style= background-color: black"></div>');
        }   
        
        var width = prompt("Tell me a width")
        var columns = prompt("Tell me a number of columns")

        chess(width, columns)
```

Comment: Use a loop to loop over the width and length (nested for loops). Keep another variable that tracks over the alternating colors like color = 0 or 1. Then I think you would just create a div with the desired width and height with the color.

Comment: Defining the same function three times doesn't really solve any problems. One thing to note, in ES6, which is the default in 2020, use `let` for variables or `const` for unchanging things instead of legacy JavaScript's `var`.

Comment: Another trick you can use now is [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which means you can do `<div style="width: ${pBoardNumber}px" ...>` instead of what you have here. Do pay close attention to your syntax, as `<div "width: 15px; ...` is not valid HTML. Make sure everything style-related is inside the `style="..."` quotes.

Comment: If your tutorial is using `document.write()` then you may want to find a more up-to-date tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I used a loop and a variable for color and it's better now. Gonna give it to the professor and see how he resolves it.